# SilverStripe File Upload Fails

Tags: php, silverstripe

I'm trying to upload Excel spread sheets and Word documents to a sub-folder of /assets/.

As you can see by the screenshot I'm unable to upload them however I can upload other file types such as .jpg. This is despite the fact that they are listed as allowed extensions.

I have tried adding the following to mysite/_config.php:

```
File::$allowed_extensions[] = 'xls';
File::$allowed_extensions[] = 'xlsx';
File::$allowed_extensions[] = 'doc';
File::$allowed_extensions[] = 'docx';
```

and have tried adding the following to mysite/_config/config.yml as recommended [here](http://doc.silverstripe.org/en/developer_guides/forms/field_types/uploadfield/?_ga=1.3624880.18846112.1427232156):

```
  File: 
      allowed_extensions: 
        - xls
        - xlsx
        - doc
        - docx
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Framework: 3.1.12
CMS: 3.1.12

Thanks.

[Screenshot](http://www.silverstripe.org/assets/forum/attachments/fileuploaderror.jpg)

Comment: That's strange. I just tested this with a fresh install of SilverStripe 3.1.12 and I am able to upload xlsx and docx files fine, with out any modifications. Maybe this is a server issue.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, 3dgoo, it's refusing to work locally, on the UAT server and on the production server. I'm contacting the hosts now regarding this but it is a strange issue.

Comment: Can you open up Chrome/Firefox/Internet Explorer developer tools and have a look at the response back from the server when the upload fails? I know the "Forbidden" message is really unhelpful, currently the CMS isn't correctly handling non-200 HTTP errors with helpful messages (they are there, just won't display them).

Comment: Thanks Turnerj, Chrome tells me that it was a 403 with the message "[{"error":"File extension does not match known MIME type"}]"

I'm looking into this now.

Comment: Awesome, that's something we can work with. Do you have the [`silverstripe-mimevalidator`](https://github.com/silverstripe-labs/silverstripe-mimevalidator) module installed?

Comment: I've just discovered this module now and have added it to my project.

Comment: Have a bit of a play around with that module to see if it helps (as I couldn't find any references to that particular error message outside of that module). If you are still stuck, tag me with @Turnerj (so I get notified) and I will see if there is anything more I can add.

Comment: @Turnerj Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76942/discussion-between-josh-m-and-turnerj).

Comment: Are `docx` and `xlsx` in the list of allowed extensions in `assets/.htaccess` ? Adding it to `File:allowed_extensions` is not enough, you'll have to edit the htaccess file as well... in the default file they are allowed though, but maybe you're using another/older version?